# using objects to determine leapyear or not

Tags: c#, object

I'm trying to work through some problems I found on a site and have gotten confused.
It goes like this: Write a C# Program Checks Whether the Entered Year is a Leap Year or Not. When A year is divided by 4. If remainder becomes 0 then the year is called a leap year..

And the solution provided is this:

```
/*
 * C# Program to Check Whether the Entered Year is a Leap Year or Not
 */
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Program
{
    class leapyear
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            leapyear obj = new leapyear();
            obj.readdata();
            obj.leap();
        }
        int y;
        public void readdata()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Year in Four Digits : ");
            y = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        public void leap()
        {
            if ((y % 4 == 0 && y % 100 != 0) || (y % 400 == 0))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is a Leap Year", y);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a Leap Year", y);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

So, on the first line, they declare leapyear. It seems that this is a type, no? Or referring to the class name?
then they have called it 'obj', and then refer to obj.readdata, etc.

I'm very lost with what is going on here, if somebody could help by explaining this for me please? Thank you

Comment: You got confused because this is a bad example. A good example will provide what is necessary to solve the problem. This example consists of 50% unneeded junk. That indeed *is* confusing. Get better examples.

Comment: plus it also has an omission with respect to how the leap years are calculated. there are no leap years on years divisible by 1000.

Comment: Agreed, thanks. Errrr....Any suggestions on where to find c# problems with explanations and examples that are well written please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code is strange. It would set off at least two flags if I'd do a code review. Maybe it was written by a Java coder? Consider this example, maybe it's easier to understand:

```
using System;

namespace Program
{
  // this is a class. Because there are no free functions in C#,
  // everything has to be in a class.
  internal static class LeapYearFinderApplication
  {
    // this is the main entry point for your application
    internal static void Main()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Enter the Year in Four Digits : ");

      var inputYear = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 

      var inputYearIsLeapYear = IsLeapYear(inputYear);

      if (inputYearIsLeapYear)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is a Leap Year", inputYear);
      }
      else
      {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a Leap Year", inputYear);
      }

      Console.ReadLine();
    }

    internal static bool IsLeapYear(int year)
    {
      return (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's a whole lot easier to understand nvoigt. Errrr....Any suggestions on where to find c# problems with explanations and examples that are well written please? What i wanna do is start writing code. I'm sick of reading theory about it and am still struggling with syntax, so just wanna start practicing

Comment: I don't know any good internet tutorials (though there have to be some) I always used books. But learning C# has been a while, you should look at the book seller of your choice for newer ones than I used fifteen years back :)

Answer (score 0):

Here leapyear is just the name of your app class. It is instantiated so it can call the functions readdata and leap.

Try to call readdata without leapyear, and it will not work, as it is inside the class leapyer.

I hope it helped you !

Answer (score 0):

This is fun! Just finished the first one :)
https://projecteuler.net/

Answer (score -1):

On the first line leapyear is a clsaa and obj is object of class leapyear in Main(Which is static) funtion.

So in a static function reference is required for non-static member (readdata() and leap()).